# Find in MS Word 365: Search for single digit without decimal before and after

Tags: ms-word

I'm trying to locate all single digits 0 to replace them with (-)
The search term I'm using now is:

```
<(0{1})>
```

The issue with this one is that it finds the zero in 0.1 or 1.0 while I only wants it to find numbers with 0 only
The 0 are included in tables cell, so no space before or after the digit, just a single digit inside a table cell

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers). That said, for content *outside* a table Find = ([!,.])0([!,.]) Replace = \1-\2 Even that will fail where 0. terminates a sentence.